# Logical Coq Proof related to map function

Tags: functional-programming, logic, coq, proof

I am trying to prove the following Lemma:

```
forall (A B : Type) (f : A -> B) (l : list A) (y : B),
    In y (map f l) <->
    exists x, f x = y /\ In x l.
```

I begin by splitting to handle the first direction, then do induction on l, then the base case is easy. But past that I get stuck. I think it's something to do with exists x and how I cannot get x to line up with x0 no matter where I try introducing x. Help!

Comment: `induction l; firstorder; subst; constructor; reflexivity.`

Comment: About your question; to handle the second case, you know that `In y (map f (a :: l))` which is really two cases - either `y` is in the head or in the tail of the list.  Do inversion on this fact to split on this information. Then it is easy to see that the `x` that is asked for is the `a` that pops up after the inversion.

Comment: I don't think `inversion` is necessary (probably best avoided in most cases anyway), especially here since a simple `destruct` is enough to examine the two cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your problem about `x0`, if this is about Coq automatically renaming `x` to `x0`.

If I were to tackle your goal I would do it as follows:

```
Goal forall (A B : Type) (f : A -> B) (l : list A) (y : B),
    In y (map f l) <->
    exists x, f x = y /\ In x l.
Proof.
  intros A B f l y. split.
  - intro h. induction l as [| a l ih].
    + contradict h.
    + simpl in h. destruct h as [h | h].
      * exists a. split.
        -- assumption.
        -- left. reflexivity.
      * specialize (ih h). destruct ih as [x [e i]].
        exists x. split.
        -- assumption.
        -- right. assumption.
```

Perhaps you wanted to line up the induction hypothesis and the goal to apply it directly?
Unfortunately I think you have to do as I do, by first destructing the induction hypothesis into an `x` and its properties and then reconstruct the goal where you stipulate it's in the tail of `l`.